# TSQL updating/deleting from JunctionTable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having difficulty figuring out the correct way to manage the following scenario.

I have 3 tables Categories, Listing, Junction

I'm using the Junction table for many-to-many relationships between my Categories & Listing tables, as any given record inside my Listing table can be assigned 1 or many Categories from the Categories table.

I've figured out how to INSERT correctly into both. Now my predicament is Updating.

If a user wants to Update their Listing to new categories then my code needs to delete any existing records in the JunctionTable and replace with new ones. How can I write a SQL statement that accomplishes that?

These are my two insert statements that fire when i'm adding a listing.

```
INSERT INTO BND_Listing_testing
(Company,Doors,Address,Address2,City,Region,Country,PostalCode,Lat,Long,Phone,Fax,Website,Description,Actualized,Verified,IMG1,IMG2,IMG3,IMG4,DateAdded)
VALUES
('[Company]','[Doors]','[Address]','[Address2]','[City]','[Region]','[Country]','[PostalCode]','[Lat]','[Long]','[Phone]','[Fax]','[Website]','[Description]','[Actualized]','[Verified]','[Image1]','[Image2]','[Image3]','[Image4]','[DateAdded]')

select scope_identity()
```

I'm storing the Identity of the above query in a token [ScopedLID] for the following query

```
DECLARE @CatIDStr VARCHAR(100) = '[CatID]',@CatID VARCHAR(100) = ''

WHILE LEN(@CatIDStr) > 0
BEGIN

   IF CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr) = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @CatID = @CatIDStr
      SET @CatIDStr = ''
   END  
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT @CatID = SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,0,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr))                                        
     SELECT @CatIDStr=SUBSTRING(@CatIDStr,CHARINDEX(',',@CatIDStr)+1,LEN(@CatIDStr))
   END

   INSERT INTO BND_ListingJunction_testing (Junc_LID,Junc_CatID)
   Values ('[ScopedLID]',@CatID) 

END
```

Comment: Use trigger? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx

Comment: @DVT Thanks for the suggestion i'll read that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a transaction.  Within that transaction first delete all rows from the junction table for the specified listing, and second add new rows for the selected combinations of listing and category.

Comment: @rd_neilsen would you happen to have a page with an example somewhere I could look at?

Comment: I don't have an example at hand that's directly pertinent to your code, but really all you should need to do is add a delete command between the code in your two blocks above:  "delete from BND_ListingJunction_testing where Junc_LID = ScopedLID;"  Wrapping this delete statement and your code to insert data into the junction table in a transaction is just protection against data loss.